# Proof of $L^p $ norm

Tags: limits, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Can someone show me how to proof this ?
$$\sqrt[p]{\sum_i {a_i}^p}\to \max a_i \quad\text{ if }p\to\infty.$$

Comment: guess there is a $1/n$ missing for this to be true...

Comment: @SpettroDiA He wrote $\sqrt[p]{\text{stuff}}$. Perhaps, what's missing is the absolute value of the $a_i$. And a $\sup$ instead of $\max$, if we stand by the tag "lp-spaces"

Comment: There is no need for 1/n. This limit is also known as Chebyshev distance. Thank for help.

Comment: This is false for general sequences. Simply take $a_n = 1$ for all $n$ to see this. If we assume $(a_n) \in l^p$ for some $p>0,$ it's true.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $\forall i, a_i \le 0$

We have :$$\sum_i a_i^p \sim k \max_i a_i^p$$ where $k$ is the number of times the number $\max_i a_i$ appears in the sum.

Thus $$\sqrt[p]{\sum_i a_i^p}\sim \sqrt[p]k\max_i{a_i} \sim \max_i{a_i}$$

(since $k\ge1$)

Comment: It is a finite sum of geometric sequences, not a series. The preponderant term is the geometric sequence with the greatest value (all others are negligible)

Comment: Well, the tag was "lp-spaces". However, I guess he still uses $\max$ instead of $\sup$.